# How can I create a dynamic capsule which is always trying to "stand up"?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a mechanic similar to this
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6OCN.png)
Basically capsules always trying to stand, when they collide with gameobject their topside is just rotating, how can I achieve this mechanic?

Comment: try it out, when you get stuck at something concrete, then you should post your question

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question currently needs more focus, your attempts and where you got stuck.

Comment: Try a rigidbody with an offset centre of mass?